# How to print only selected items (selected with a checkbox) in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, checkbox

I've made two tables, and I added one checkbox for each.

[image: picture]

The checkboxes aren't default checkbox, but it's an image that gets changed on click, here the code:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-customPrint-md no-print" ng-click="checkBoxPrint2 = !checkBoxPrint2"><i class="fa fa-1x" ng-class="checkBoxPrint2 ? 'fa-square-o' : 'fa-check-square-o'"></i></button>
```

so onClick it changes the FontAwesome icon.

Then I have a Print Button, which prints the page following the print css rules:

```
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-custom-md pull-right" ng-click="vm.$window.print()"><i class="fa fa-print fa-2x"></i></button>
```

Now I would like to know how can I make it print ONLY the tables that have the checkbox checked (meaning with "fa-check-square-o" icon) ?
My initial idea was doing it with ng-class, so when the button is pushed, it gives a "noPrint" class to the element that hides it from print, does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-show or ng-hide based on your boolean properties to hide/show tables.

I'm not sure that I understand your question perfectly but a simple example would be:

```
$scope.showElement = false;

<div ng-show="showElement">This only shows if the variable is true</div>
```

In your case you could use checkBoxPrint2 as an expression for ng-show/hide, on each one of the elements that you would like to hide. You could for example only keep the headers always visible but hide the contents.

Here's more information and examples for you:

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-show.asp